# How to listen KeyEvent in main activity when Android speech recognition popuped

Tags: android, android-activity, voice-recognition, keyevent, speech

I use activity to call Google speech recognition Activity. My question it that, can we listen   keyevent in main activity when Google Speech Reg Activity already popuped??

any ideas? Though, i know that main activity will be onPause when Google Activity popuped.

here is my android code

```
public class TestSpeechReg extends Activity {
private TextView txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button startButton = new Button(this);
    startButton.setText("Start TestSpeechReg");
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             startSpeechReg(TestSpeechReg.this);
        }
    });

    txtText = new TextView(this);
    txtText.setText("###################");

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(startButton);
    layout.addView(txtText);

    setContentView(layout);
}

// voice recognition
public static final int REQUESTCODE_SPEECHRECOGNITION = 0x1000;

private void startSpeechReg(Activity context) {
    Log.i("TestSpeechReg", "openSpeechRecognition");
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_SPEECHRECOGNITION);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUESTCODE_SPEECHRECOGNITION: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtText.setText(text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the UI (e.g. listen to key presses) then interact with the speech recognizer via the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)-class (requires API level 8), which does not start a new activity. Your current code starts a new activity, i.e. your UI is stopped (i.e. not just `onPause`, but also `onStop` is called, I think).

Comment: Thx. I dont want use Speech Reg as background service, but just activity. And UI is paused (coz. the new activity dont cover over main activity.)